# Ruby post with net::hhtp.post_form

Tags: ruby, activerecord, post

i have reduced this to as little as possible but wondering what i am doing wrong with this little ruby file:

```
params ={'title'=>'qwert', 'fulltext'=>'qwert', 'user_twitter_id'=>'qwert'}
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3000/details/'), params)
puts res.body
```

This does result in a record being created but none of the params being inserted, yet they seem recognised?

```
Started POST "/details/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-31 12:37:02 +0000
Processing by DetailsController#create as 
Parameters: {"title"=>"qwert", "fulltext"=>"qwert", "user_twitter_id"=>"qwert"}
AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "details" ("title", "fulltext", "user_twitter_id",     "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-10-31 12:37:02.401881', '2011-  10-31 12:37:02.401881')
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/details/23
Completed 302 Found in 185ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard Rails you need a root element (you don't show the controller action, so I must assume):

```
params = {:detail => {...}}
```

BTW, a higher-level library as [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) may come handy ([edit] Marian notes that nested hashes are not managed by Net::HTTP, so try rest-client)

Comment: using the root doesn't seem to work and kinda breaks how the parameters seem to get passed ' Parameters: {"detail"=>"[\"user_twitter_id\", \"qwert\"]"}'

also what sort of advantages would a gem offer?

Comment: Net::HTTP can't encode nested hashes for params by itself, either do it manually , or use a higher level library like tokland proposed. (or use another encoding, i.e. send your params as json body, not form-encoded)